# How to hook Raspberry Pi with Electret Microphone to detect sound levels in dB?

Tags: python, microphone, raspberry-pi3, decibel

I have to detect sounds levels in an enclosed area, so I thought this could be the right choice.

I purchased an Electret Microphone with Auto Gain from Adafruit
https://www.adafruit.com/product/1713

I am trying to interface it with a raspberry pi 3 to detect sound levels, however, I have not been able to find a solution for it as most of the tutorials are for Arduino or other breakout boards, does anyone have a solution for this?

Understood that the output from the microphone is analogue typed and I have an adc converter ADS1115 and MCP3008 that would be useful, but I have not been able to search for the solution that would guide me on using the microphone and the converter.

//EDIT
I have been able to hook the sensor to the ADC and MCP, however, however, the values stay constant and do not seem to change at all, even playing songs into the microphone do not change the values. I get a constant value ranging from 200 to 300 on MCP and around 1056 on ADC.

I need to collect the sound levels and put them up into a server.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should hook up the ADC board to the raspberry in accordance to their communication. MCP uses SPI which is serial interface, and is a 10 bits ADC which should give you 0 to 1023 levels.
The best way to test if your ADC is working properly is to use a potentiometer and vary it, check with an oscilloscope the SIGNAL DOUT of your ADC. If you don't have an oscilloscope. You can try with multimeter.

Also if you could provide the wiring connections you've made so we could check the SPI protocol.

EDIT// One last think I've realise, is that you bought a microphone with Auto Gain control. That means you will not be able to measure sound pressure level with it. Try using a microphone which will give you the amplitude of the signal (envelope) like [THIS ONE](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12642)